# Population Model In VB - Wont take input values

Tags: vb.net, integer, double

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Birthrate As Double, GenerationNum As Integer
        Dim PopulationJuveniles, PopulationAdults, PopulationSeniles As Double
        Dim SurvivalJuveniles, SurvivalAdults, SurvivalSeniles As Double
        Dim NewJuveniles, NewAdults, NewSeniles As Double

        If Not Double.TryParse(txtBirthRate.Text, Birthrate) _
          OrElse Integer.TryParse(txtGenerations.Text, GenerationNum) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numbers for birthrate and generations")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Not Double.TryParse(txtPJ.Text, PopulationJuveniles) _
          OrElse Double.TryParse(txtPA.Text, PopulationAdults) _
          OrElse Double.TryParse(txtPS.Text, PopulationSeniles) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numbers for populations")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Not Double.TryParse(txtSJ.Text, SurvivalJuveniles) _
          OrElse Double.TryParse(txtSA.Text, SurvivalAdults) _
          OrElse Double.TryParse(txtSS.Text, SurvivalSeniles) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numbers for survival")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Counter As Integer = 1 To GenerationNum
            NewJuveniles = PopulationAdults * Birthrate
            NewAdults = PopulationJuveniles * SurvivalJuveniles 'the juveniles have matured 
            NewSeniles = PopulationAdults * SurvivalAdults 'Add + PopulationSeniles * SurvivalSeniles if SurvivalSeniles can ever be >0
            PopulationSeniles = NewSeniles
            PopulationAdults = NewAdults
            PopulationJuveniles = NewJuveniles
            ListBox1.Items.Add(PopulationJuveniles.ToString & ", " & PopulationAdults.ToString & ", " & PopulationSeniles.ToString)
        Next
```

When i try and enter values such as a double e.g 10.1 and 5 for a integer it just says enter valid numbers but they are valid numbers!

anyone have any suggestions or numbers i can try to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the keyword NOT with every statement being evaluated.

For example:

```
If Not Double.TryParse(txtPJ.Text, PopulationJuveniles) _
  OrElse Double.TryParse(txtPA.Text, PopulationAdults) _
  OrElse Double.TryParse(txtPS.Text, PopulationSeniles) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numbers for populations")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Should be changed to:

```
If Not Double.TryParse(txtPJ.Text, PopulationJuveniles) _
  OrElse Not Double.TryParse(txtPA.Text, PopulationAdults) _
  OrElse Not Double.TryParse(txtPS.Text, PopulationSeniles) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numbers for populations")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

---

Explanation:

In VB.Net, each boolean expression is evaluated on its own, so the first NOT only affects the first expression. If you want the same functionalty with each expression, then each expression needs its own NOT keyword.